# About real symmetric matrix multiplied by diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

Recently, I found an important matrix in analog circuit domain and it need to be proved diagonalized. Then I try to resolve it into a small problem that is:

> if there are a $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix $A$ with rank $m$ ($m<n$) and a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix $B$ with rank $n$, can matrix $AB$ be diagonalized?

I can not solve this problem, I would appreciate it if you can help me. You can ask me for more details about the original problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please avoid "do my homework for me"-style questions. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: (Also, use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make your maths look pretty.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments and I have modified my question

Comment: A spell check is likely to win you some more support too.

Comment: I'm sorry for making some spell mistakes and I have corrected them.

Answer (score 1):

What a strange question (what is the point of insisting that $A$ not have full rank?). Anyway try
$$
  A=\pmatrix{0&1&0\cr1&0&0\cr0&0&0\cr},\qquad
  B=\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&-1&0\cr0&0&\sqrt{42}\cr}.
$$